# How to use BSplineFunction for calculating derivative

Tags: interpolation, splines

I have a set of data like the following

```
data = {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3},......}
```

Now I use

```
b = BSplineFunction[data, SplineDegree -> 5];
```

Now I don't know how to extract the interpolating function from b to calculate it's derivative.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: aside from your  question, a bspline is not a good way to approximate data. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to find the maximum of the function represented by "data". I have tried spline, but it gives a fluctuating plot near the maximum. So it will be hard to find position of the maximum by using Bisection method.

Comment: If anyone knows how to distill the piecewise polynomial out of a `BSplineFunction` that would be interesting to see.

Comment: Why not use `Interpolation[]` instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply take the derivative, but note you are differentiating w/ respect to the parameter:

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
f = BSplineFunction[pts];
g[t_] = D[f[t], t]  (* g is a new BSplineFunction *)
```

use chain rule to get `dydx`:

```
dydx[t_?NumericQ] := #[[2]]/#[[1]] &@g[t];
tangents = Table[{f[t], f[t] + .2 {1, dydx[t]}}, {t, 0, 1, .1}];
ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1} , 
 Epilog -> Arrow /@ tangents, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

obtaining the extrema..

```
ext = Table[ t /. FindRoot[dydx[t], {t, s}] , {s, {.2, .5, .9}}];
(* or use FindRoot[ g[t][[2]] , {t, .. }] *)
Show[Graphics[{ BSplineCurve[pts] , Arrow /@ tangents , Red, 
 PointSize[.02], Point[f /@ ext ] , Blue , Point /@ pts} ],  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

note that a bspline doesn't pass through its control points (in blue) so this is not a good way to approximate data.

( note this works fine w/ `SplineDegree->5`, but you need at least 6 points. )

Comment: when i run your code, it gives me the following errors:  Part 2 of BSplineFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][t] does not exist. >> , The expression #2 cannot be used as a part specification. >>

Comment: Add the `?NumericQ` pattern to `dydx` (see edit). (be sure to do `Clear[dydx];`  first)

Comment: @george2079 can we now directly use second/third BSplineFunction derivatives in MMA 12.2`?